# Http post request NullPointerException OutputStream

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-post, httprequest, outputstream

I'm trying to fire an http post request and 
my problem is that I'm getting an NullpointerException, i think i know where but i dont know why.

the code is

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
      URL url = new URL(targetURL);

      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
           "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
               Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
      connection.setUseCaches (false);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      // Send request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
      wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
      wr.flush();
      wr.close();

      // Get Response
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
      }
      rd.close();
      log.info("Http request response '{}': ",response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error while sending http post request.");
      e.printStackTrace();


    } finally {

      if(connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
      }
    }
```

My error output is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.toURI(ParseUtil.java:261)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:905)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1014)
```

which is at line: `DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());`

It seems that the problem is to make a Http URL Connection but my target Url ( the url where i want to send my request) is correct: Target url: 'http:localhost:8080/project/externalData' (its the url of my (Spring) RequestMethod in my url pattern. Also my params strings seems to be right PARAMS: 'salutation=Mister&givenname=Matt&familyname=Jones'. 
or isn't it correct to use DataOutputStream?

Thx for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have check your code its working fine. I guess there problem in URL either its wrong or URL has some character that are not able to parse.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Snippet {

public static void main(String args[]){
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

`String targetURL="http://localhost:7001/smartquote_nodocuments/session";
 String urlParameters="timezoneOffset=-330&daylightSaving=false";
    try {

    URL url = new URL(targetURL);

      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
           "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
               Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
      connection.setUseCaches (false);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      // Send request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
      wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
      wr.flush();
      wr.close();

      // Get Response
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
      }
      rd.close();
      System.out.println("Http request response '{}': "+response.toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}}`

it worked fine and gives expected result